# Изменение ширины блоков

Tags: html, css, css3

Имеется три колонки(блока) одинаковой ширины, как сделать, что бы при изменении размеров окна уменьшалась сперва ширина правого блока до ширины контента внутри него и после начать изменять ширину центрального блока по той же схеме

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите, чтобы работало это без брейкпоинтов? И еще пара наводящих вопросов. Чем обусловлена ширина внутреннего контента? Это какой-то элемент с фиксированной шириной или несколько элементов? Если несколько, то могут ли они переносится на уровень ниже, если не помещаются внутри родительской колонки? Без какой-то конкретики, даже сложно придумать, в каком направлении двигаться. И забегая вперёд, вы рассматриваете использование JS? Т.к. пока сомневаюсь, что без него получится задуманное.

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо! Я несколько лет не трогал css, думал может что-нибудь появилось для решения таких моментов. Такое поведение не обязательно, по другому сделаю, более стандартно